# How does Windows decide whether to use Deflate or Deflate64 for zipping files?

Tags: windows, operating-system, deflate

Windows Explorer uses the Deflate64 compression method for its zip files, rather than Deflate.
Is this behaviour consistent across "current" Windows versions?

I tried one way.
I created one zip file whose size is 2.69 GB,
and one folder whose size is more than 1.23.

After  zipping  both of them, the zip file was created using Deflate64 and its size was 3.19 GB.

I would like to know how Windows decides whether to zip the file using Deflate64 or Deflate? What are the conditions required to create Deflate64 zip files?

Answer (score 0):

See this [note](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17802#issuecomment-231808916):

> Windows 7/8/10 all use Deflate64. The cutoff in zip size where it
> switches from Deflate to Deflate64 appears to be 2 gigs. The number of
> files within the zip is irrelevant to the compression type chosen e.g.
> one 2.5 gig file will be Deflate64’ed the same as five 0.5 gig files.

Comment: Thank you for replying , i  created a zip file using windows explorer  whose size was 2.5 gb , but that zip was created using deflate and not deflate 64

Comment: Then try 3 GB. Note that 2.5 GiB ~= 2.7 GB. "GB" can be ambiguous.

Comment: I created a folder whose size was 7.42 gb  after zipping the folder, zip file was created and the size was 3.71 Gb and it is zipped in defate and not defalte 64  ,  Does Windows randomly decides when to  use defalte 64 ?

Comment: Beats me. Perhaps Microsoft has changed the logic over time.

Comment: Ok, Can you let me know if there are any forums, i posted one over here also but no reply yet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/969084/how-does-windows-decide-whether-to-use-deflate-or.html